# Slight issue with parsing a jsonP request from Twitter api

Tags: jquery, twitter, jsonp

I'm having an issue parsing a jsonP request from Twitter api.

My code is as follows:

```
var processRequest = function(data){

        console.log(data); //outputs what I believe to be correct 
        var result = $.parseJSON(data);
        var text = '';
        console.log("1");//outputs
        $.each(result, function(){
            console.log("2");// doesn't output
            text = this['created_at'];
        });
        console.log(text);//doesn't output
}

$(document).ready(function () {


var url = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=0&include_rts=0&screen_name=DockersHamptons&count=1&callback=processRequest";

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {},
    success: function (data){
        if(typeof(data.error) != 'undefined') {
            if(data.error != ''){
                //Shouldn't hit here
            }                   
        } else {
            //Shouldn't hit here.   
        }
    }
});
```

});

The error I get in the firebug console is:
TypeError: a is null

But it says that error is located in my "jquery-1.7.1.min.js" file on line 2.

I also tried playing around with this in jsfiddle and this setup doesn't writing anything to the `<span></span>`:

http://jsfiddle.net/kdP8b/1/

But this setup does:

http://jsfiddle.net/3tHXN/2/

Does this mean there is something in the twitter api that is causing it to come up as invalid json format?

EDIT:
I'm still having the same issue with this, but I wanted to add to it in case it might help.

Jquery is defined by the time it hits the line with the $.parseJSON() because I tried adding jquery code before and after that line.  So the issue is definitely with what is returned by twitter's api.  But I find it hard to believe they are giving me invalid json formated data.  So is there something I have to do to the result before using $.parseJSON()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found the solution on another site.  My issue was that twitter api already returns a well formed json string.  So I just had to remove the use of $.parseJSON().

```
var processRequest = function(data){
var text = '';
$.each(data, function(){
    text = this['text'];
});
$("#twitter_update_list").html("<li>"+text+"</li>");
}
```